# Unable to add LESS THAN check in condition for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following which works nicely in the controller:

```
@packers = Packer.find(:all, :conditions => { :p_team => "t" ,  :p_cspa_date => DateTime.now }, :order => "p_name")
```

However I'm unable to make the following work:

```
@packers = Packer.find(:all, :conditions => { :p_team => "t" ,  :p_cspa_date < ?, DateTime.now }, :order => "p_name")
```

Essentially

```
@packers = Packer.find(:all, :conditions => { :p_team => "t" ,  :p_cspa_date LESS THAN DateTime.now }, :order => "p_name")
```

The schema from the console is follows:

```
irb(main):064:0> Packer.last.p_cspa_date 
Packer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "packers".* FROM "packers" ORDER BY "packers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> Fri, 22 Mar 2013
irb(main):065:0> Packer.last.p_team
Packer Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "packers".* FROM "packers" ORDER BY "packers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> true
irb(main):066:0>
```

Comment: Remember to include error messages/output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `:p_cspa_date < ?` with `"p_cspa_date < ?"` or the whole thing with:

```
@packers = Packer.where("p_team = 't' AND p_cspa_date < ?", DateTime.now).order(:p_name)
```